# GPUImage: How to apply different filters to an image, scale them down and tile results to the output image

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm new to the [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) library.

I'm using it to obtain frame from the camera and filter them in real-time. I'm using different filter parameters for the filter I am developing.

I figured out how to filter the camera image in parallel with different filters but what I'd like to do now is to output a result image where 4 filtered images are tiled together to make a big output image.

My thinking has been that I can chain `GPUImageTransformFilter` instances and `GPUImageAddBlendFilter` instances to obtain the composed image. For instance, in the simplest case of scaling two images down and putting them side by side:

```
self.transform1 = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];
_transform1.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.5, 0.5);

self.transform2 = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];
_transform2.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.5, 0.5), 1.0, 0.0);

self.blendFirst1 = [[GPUImageAddBlendFilter alloc] init];

[_transform1 addTarget:_blendFirst1];
[_transform2 addTarget:_blendFirst1];
```

This, however results in both images being scaled and overlaid each other and the result being translated to edge of the image with the other half empty.

I'd appreciate any pointers on how to scale and tile smaller images to make one big image.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could do this with transforms, you're looking at three blends to get your four images into one still frame. That's not going to be the fastest or most memory-efficient path to make this work.

Instead, I'd suggest subclassing GPUImageTwoInputFilter or creating a totally new multi-input filter based on that and then using that filter to pull all four of your images in for rendering. People have made three- or four-filter input blends by doing this, and that would probably be your most efficient path here.

The fragment shader for your filter could render four quads, one for each input image, or have shaders that selectively sampled from the four textures to provide the appropriate color at a given pixel. The former would be faster, but might require you to write a little more OpenGL ES code in modifying the base blend filter. The latter would use simple tweaks to the vertex and fragment shaders, but the conditionals in those shaders might slow things down.